# Skipping the div block in global header file in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a php header file where i wrote some global code. All the php pages in my network use that page by

```
include_once(TEMPLATEPATH."includes/html_header.php");
```

However at one of the pages from the network i want to skip a functionality of html_header page. I have a div named "mySocialTool" which is present in header and used in all pages. Can i skip that div block being used in one of my php files say sidebarCalender.php ?

Comment: Include a different header.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but `include_once` isn't a function, and you should avoid using that confusing syntax.  Instead use `include_once TEMPLATEPATH . 'includes/html_header.php';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set a variable before including the header file, and then check the value of that variable in your header file. Based on the value you either show or do not show the div.

In file where you want to skip the div:

```
define('HIDE_DIV', true);
include_once TEMPLATEPATH . "includes/html_header.php";
```

In header template:

```
if (! defined('HIDE_DIV') || HIDE_DIV == false) {
    echo 'YOUR DIV';
}
```

Comment: I'd advise to use a constant. If it's a variable, it can be modified before reaching `include_once TEMPLATEPATH . "includes/html_footer.php";`, thus screwing up the HTML structure.

Comment: Updated my answer to use a constant. If you don't like this answer your other option is to include a different template, as suggested by @Waleed Khan.